# C++ doesn't work uniform and all variable defines

Tags: c++, c++11, opengl, glsl, glsles

```
#include <windows.h>  // for MS Windows
#include <GL/glut.h>  // GLUT, include glu.h and gl.h
#include <vector> 

uniform vec2 lightpos;
uniform vec3 lightColor;
uniform float screenHeight;
uniform vec3 lightAttenuation;
uniform float radius;

uniform sampler2D texture;

void main()
{       
    vec2 pixel=gl_FragCoord.xy;     
    pixel.y=screenHeight-pixel.y;   
    vec2 aux=lightpos-pixel;
    float distance=length(aux);
    float attenuation=1.0/(lightAttenuation.x+lightAttenuation.y*distance+lightAttenuation.z*distance*distance);    
    vec4 color=vec4(attenuation,attenuation,attenuation,1.0)*vec4(lightColor,1.0);  
    gl_FragColor = color;//*texture2D(texture,gl_TexCoord[0].st);
}
```

> Errors
>   'uniform' does not name a type
>   'vec2' was not declared in this scope
>   'screenHeight' was not declared in this scope
>   expected ';' before 'aux'
>   'aux' was not declared in this scope

etc.

I use Dev C++ and ...

[projects parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKpyY.png)

[/GL/ header subfiles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDrBV.png)

Don't hesitate to write if any other information is needed. I added what I know. I have done the opengl project before. But know I have to make like this   [YouTube Video, OpenGL 2D lighting using shaders](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fsbECSpwtig)

Comment: I recommend to read [LearnOpenGL - Compiling a shader](https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Hello-Triangle) and [LearnOpenGL - Shaders](https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Shaders)

Answer (score 1):

GLSL just look like C, it's not actually C. The code has to be compiled by a different compiler (an external one like `glslc` or the driver provided OpenGL compiler) and it runs on the GPU as part of a render pass.

Comment: I want to apply the light intensity like this, is Dev C ++ wrong compiler ?

Comment: @caginagirdemir: GLSL is not C; you don't compile it with a C compiler the way you do your C code.

Answer (score 0):

This is a shader program, not a c++ program. You have to compile it with a shader compiler.